# Stopping Jquery slider and breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that goes through a list of images. Once it reaches the last image I want it to break and run a function. I tried a `while` loop with the length, but the slider breaks.

```
function slider() {
    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slide = 'li';
    var $transitionTime = 1000;
    var $transitionTimeBetweenSlides = 4000;
    var $length = $slide.find('li').length;

    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transitionTime);

    $interval = setInterval(function () {
        var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();
        slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
        slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transitionTime);

        if (slides().length == $i + 1) // loop to start
            slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transitionTime);
        slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');

    }, $transitionTime + $transitionTimeBetweenSlides);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with 'slider breaks'? if you want to break window.setInterval form ticking, use clearInterval()

Comment: make a fiddle and tell us where its breaking?

Comment: It was not breaking due to the code, it was breaking because of my browser. Right now I just am looking the slider to stop on the last image, but I am having trouble doing it.